# Function with structure as argument producing error: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007efd47b

Tags: c++, pointers

I've made an addDepartment function that takes a structure as an argument. When I enter input to initialize the "dept[counter].departmentHead" at the bottom of the function, it triggers the error message.

I'm copying the logic from another code I wrote using classes instead of structures and that one works fine so I'm really not sure why this one isn't working. Tried messing with the index to make sure I wasn't going over the size of the array but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Department{
    string departmentName;
    string departmentHead;
    int departmentID;
    double departmentSalary;
};

//...

Department addDepartment(Department dept[3]){
    int repeat=0;
    int counter=0;
    if (counter>2){
        cout<<"The array is full, you can not add any more Departments."<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Please Enter Department Details:"<<endl;
        cout << "Department ID : ";
        cin >> dept[counter].departmentID;
        for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
            for (int y=x+1; y<3; y++){
                if(dept[x].departmentID==dept[y].departmentID)
                    repeat++;
            }
        }
        if(repeat!=0)
            cout<<"Value must be unique!"<<endl;
        else{
            cout << "Department Name : ";
            cin >> dept[counter].departmentName;
            cout << "Head of Department : ";
            cin >> dept[counter].departmentHead;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

//...

int main()
{
    Employee emp[5];
    Department dept[3];
    initialID(emp,dept,0);
    initialID(emp,dept,1);
    int response;
    while(response!=6){
        displayMenu();
        cout<< "Please make a selection : \n";
        cin >> response;
        while((response!=1)&&(response!=2)&&(response!=3)&&(response!=4)&&(response!=5)&&(response!=6)){
            cout<< "Please enter a valid choice (1 - 6): ";
            cin >> response;
        }
        if(response==1){
            addDepartment(dept);
        }
        else if(response==2){
            //addEmployee(emp,dept);
        }
        else if(response==3){

        }
        else if(response==4){

        }
        else if(response==5){
            //salaryReport(dept);
        }
    }
        cout << "Thank you, goodbye.";  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look C++ designed code at all. It looks like C code instead.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What makes you think so, @Jack? It's not the most beautiful piece of C++, but it definitely is C++.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it didn’t say it’s not C++, I’ saying it’s not designed as it should be in C++, free functions with arrays passed as arguments? Why there’s no like Store class

Comment: @Jack I am using structures instead of classes as is required by our professor. I coded this program in a previous assignment using classes but am not allowed to do so this time.

Comment: C++ has lots of free function and not just those inherited from C and there's nothing wrong with that. Also, there are no arrays passed as arguments (it's impossible, both in C and C++). Lastly, what is a "like Store class". Seriously, even if you have the right arguments in your head, @Jack, the part that you dumped here is not helpful in improving either the question or the author's C++ skills.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt free functions are meant to be stateless. Here I see a `Departement addDepartement(Departement dept[3])`. Add a departement to what? Why is it returning a `Departement`? I'm expecting a `Store::addDepartement(int id, const string& name, const string& head, double salary)` or `(Department&& dept)`. This would have expressed intent clearly, probably also avoiding mistakes like declaring a free method returning a `Department` for no reason (and not returning it). Proper design helps a lot avoiding errors and if you are using  a language with proper features you should use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why it breaks.**
The `addDepartment` function never actually returns a department. When the function exits, the space where the return newly created Department would be is left uninitialized. This causes **undefined behavior**. The compiler tries to destruct the `Department` object like it normally would, but because it was never initialized, `free` gets called on garbage (causing the error).

We can fix this by adding a line to `addDepartment` returning the actual department:

```
Department addDepartment(Department dept[3]){
    int repeat=0;
    int counter=0;
    if (counter>2){
        cout<<"The array is full, you can not add any more Departments."<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Please Enter Department Details:"<<endl;
        cout << "Department ID : ";
        cin >> dept[counter].departmentID;
        for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
            for (int y=x+1; y<3; y++){
                if(dept[x].departmentID==dept[y].departmentID)
                    repeat++;
            }
        }
        if(repeat!=0)
            cout<<"Value must be unique!"<<endl;
        else{
            cout << "Department Name : ";
            cin >> dept[counter].departmentName;
            cout << "Head of Department : ";
            cin >> dept[counter].departmentHead;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return /* some department */;
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `addDepartment` void.

**Other considerations.** Don't pass raw C arrays to functions. It doesn't do what you intend.

If you want to pass a *copy* of an array, pass a `std::array`, which will be copied automatically:

```
Department addDepartment(std::array<Department, 3> dept);
```

If want to access the elements of an existing array, pass a pointer:

```
Department addDepartment(Department* dept, int count);
```

Comment: That might just be it. I'm a beginner so I'm still getting used to being more aware of scope. I will test to see if this solves it.

Comment: Yes I just realized I meant to make these void functions. In copying them from my other code it did not occur to me that I wasn't actually returning anything from the functions.

Comment: Ok! The other answer also had some good points about potentially having the number of elements in your arrays wrong. In general, try to use `std::vector` or `std::array`, which are actual objects. C-style arrays, like `Department dept[3];`, aren't objects in the normal sense, and they don't behave normally when passed to functions

Comment: Here's a good resource! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: One thing's missing: Compiler warnings. Compilers are actually pretty smart, they could have detected that you never return the promised value from the function and given you a hint. However, you need to turn on warnings. How to do that depends on the compiler (and its version) but should be easy to find out.

Comment: The editor I was using actually warned me about it. That’s how I caught it so quickly

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see is that you are creating an array of 3 `Department` objects in `main` and assuming that you have 5 elements in `initialID`.

Change `main` to create an array of 5 `Department` objects.

```
int main()
{
    Employee emp[5];
    Department dept[5];

    ...
```